# Oracle SQL, IF statements

Tags: sql, oracle

I’m running a query from a table that has info on account numbers, settled charges , the write off figure, and the reason for the write off; so the table is called group_write_off and the table headings, account_id, charge_settled_date, total_charge_amount, amount_written_off, write_off_reason. What I want to do, is pull everything through, so

`Select * from
group_write_off`

but for any case where the write_off_reason includes the word ‘Audit’, I want amount_written_off to show as 0 (zero), for all others i want the original amount_written_off to show.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use CASE expression.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN write_off_reason='Audit' THEN 0 ELSE amount_written_off END
FROM group_write_off
```

Also try below for checking if Audit word is present in column write_off_reason by using [**INSTR()**](https://www.w3resource.com/oracle/character-functions/oracle-instr-function.php) function

```
SELECT CASE WHEN INSTR(write_off_reason,'Audit') = 0 THEN 0 ELSE amount_written_off END
FROM group_write_off
```

If you want more words

```
SELECT CASE WHEN INSTR(write_off_reason,'Audit') = 0 THEN 0 
       WHEN INSTR(write_off_reason,'admin') = 0 THEN 0 
       ELSE amount_written_off END
FROM group_write_off
```

Comment: Excellent, many thanks. If i wish to include additional write_off reasons, for instance any write_off_reason which includes the word 'admin', how would I insert this into the code above?